# Best way to share views across areas in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have my main area and i have a member area, some of the content in the main area can be used in the member area. The two area's have their own _Layout(MasterPage).

How can i have the same content in both areas following DRY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `~/Views/Shared` folder for storing views (layouts, partials, editor and display templates) between different parts of the application.

Comment: I know the Shared folder, but the pages use two different menu. My idea so far is to make it as a partial view and then make a view the two places i need this partial view and then get it by RenderPartial.